# How many blocks make a "truncated square-pyramid garden"?

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer

A ***truncated square-pyramid*** of height \$h\$ has \$h\$ square layers where each layer has a side \$1\$ greater than the one above it, apart from the top layer which is a square of blocks with a given side length.

Here is a truncated square-pyramid of height \$7\$ and top side-length \$4\$ viewed from the side:

```
             side length   blocks
   ████          4          16
  ▐████▌         5          25
  ██████         6          36
 ▐██████▌        7          49
 ████████        8          64
▐████████▌       9          81
██████████      10         100
                   Total = 371
```

It requires \$\sum_{i=4}^{10}i^2=371\$ blocks to construct.

---

A ***truncated square-pyramid garden*** of size \$N\$ consists of truncated, square-pyramids of heights \$1\$ to \$N\$ where the \$n^{th}\$ tallest pyramid has a top side-length of \$x\$ where \$x\$ is the remainder after dividing \$N\$ by \$n\$ unless there is no remainder in which case \$x=n\$.

Here is a side-on view of a pyramid garden with \$N=6\$ pyramids, arranged from tallest to shortest:

```
N=6                ▐▌
                   ██     ██
                  ▐██▌   ▐██▌   ▐██▌
                  ████   ████   ████   ██
                 ▐████▌ ▐████▌ ▐████▌ ▐██▌ ▐▌
                 ██████ ██████ ██████ ████ ██  ██████
          height   6      5      4     3   2     1
               n   1      2      3     4   5     6
remainder of N/n   0      0      0     2   1     0
 top side-length   1      2      3     2   1     6
```

This garden takes \$337\$ blocks to construct.

#### Task

Given a positive integer, \$N\$, calculate the number of blocks required to build a *truncated square-pyramid garden* of size \$N\$.

You are not required to handle size zero (just in case that causes an edge case for anyone).

Since this is a sequence, you may instead opt to output the block counts for all gardens up to size \$N\$ (with or without a leading zero, for size zero), or generate the block counts indefinitely without input (again a leading zero is acceptable). It's not currently in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), and neither is its two-dimensional version.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in each language wins.

#### Test cases

The first \$100\$ terms of the sequence are (starting with \$N=1\$):

```
1, 9, 28, 80, 144, 337, 455, 920, 1251, 1941, 2581, 4268, 4494, 7065, 9049, 11440, 13299, 19005, 20655, 28544, 31140, 37673, 45305, 59360, 59126, 73289, 86256, 101124, 109647, 136805, 138364, 170780, 184520, 211485, 241157, 275528, 272869, 326729, 368320, 414692, 424823, 499261, 510708, 596140, 636361, 680537, 753508, 867036, 857345, 966889, 1027920, 1130172, 1197747, 1358369, 1393684, 1528840, 1571095, 1712605, 1860668, 2083248, 2023267, 2261821, 2445122, 2584136, 2685714, 2910217, 2980225, 3298056, 3459910, 3719313, 3824917, 4206640, 4128739, 4534965, 4846194, 5081240, 5308615, 5695545, 5827090, 6349936, 6395099, 6753185, 7173903, 7783720, 7688846, 8192521, 8679955, 9202980, 9429730, 10177969, 10090513, 10725680, 11134432, 11766133, 12407705, 13134004, 13024244, 13979357, 14523352, 15111244
```

---

Note: there is a surprisingly terse Jelly solution to find for this one, happy hunting!

Here's a hint that might help get you thinking about a different approach:

> In Jelly lists are 1-indexed and indexing is modular, so finding the top side-length could be calculated by using \$N\$ to index into a list of `[1,2,...,n]`.

*2022-03-15*: If you just want to see this solution I have now posted it [below](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244169/53748).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!

```python
lambda N:sum((N%~n-~h)**2for n in range(N)for h in range(n,N))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcixDkAwEADQ3VfcIr2TSpRN4hf6BZaKVptwpGqw@PWKyRvfcSe/c5fdMObVbNNsQPfntSHq8uH68VRVrdsjMASGaHixqOkL/wdLTZS/DH8qqRpFfQFwxMAJHQaSYHkehARB@QU)

Comment: `sum((N%~n+h+1)**2for n in range(N)for h in range(n,N))` saves a byte.

Comment: @Neil Yes, thank you! And I can keep the `+h+1` -> `-~h` for 62

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>63</s> 61 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval("for(x=y=0;x++<n;)for(z=0;z++<=n-x;)y+=(~-n%x+z)**2")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVPbbloxEHzPV7hIlSBA5b3Ya4ucvvUrojxELVRUCCqSRiQP/XU6Y6ojHa@9693ZmfWv57fnl@/n/e/X9fH0Y3vdTdfj9HX79nyYz3an8/wyvU95c1kuH46bBQ8@sP3AdjquL5vF@3Ka/10fP1@WH4v7e50trpu7O1z@s31JU3qUVeqrpG2VWl4lcV8ls1glLwUe5ZkWBEl3/LU0/F0r4t07giNXBmZHFsF1XjDt3PWc4VIEcGll5EYMQixqGIsYQ0q3mrmIVmQ0bbjeqhbsJIuoc@3Vg8lr4x2xZpXnkWMgb16IVlGgsZ6LFMRrlMLuNLRVpDWtoVxrM8a7eO3KnrwpIfWuFT0WyZEbQdWBuBo@nLM6@Ylihf5WIxtwthLmZKLWRviSNW70iWUJpdEjbi0UYGeMofHGJgCxDepKoFG2F@Bi9NlqrqRbMwD7MJRNwADQplTFvYjqkMeFaCAQMiGzdgARBveWVQsJgEVmAbfDSzGkm6B3a@qdwQ7Rqg92tIX1oZR3Ku3Nq1B4dA9hKJvlVoUy1l4KOShNI/dBGugknmq9ZA5FBW9CfUKQN6NoRLMgUQHikBxUStfCvsBt7//nkKhhuPawPMYiog8SM0oVwodiGJkxDCDd3QbpUasYvQAbcRsdeHMm75YVwg@rRzcOjGCOzArvFuHs@RMeDN5Vmh@2r2mPRyMbLA8TS8NaLhd3Ke13ab6b7xfp05Rur@txv5YnulL6fjq@nA7bL4fTz/ns2/l8Os8Wm@s/)

Shortened by @ophact.

Comment: `(n-1)%x` -> `~-n%x`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>58</s> 49 bytes

```r
function(N){for(i in 1:N)F=F+(x=i:N+N%%-i)%*%x
F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NPszotv0gjUyEzT8HQyk/TzdZNW6PCNtPKT9tPVVU3U1NVS7WCy632f3FiQUFOpYahlaGBTprmfwA)

Relatively straightforward implementation of the spec.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```r
function(N)sum(unlist(Map(seq,N%%-(1:N)+1:N,l=N:1))^2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NPs7g0V6M0LyezuETDN7FAozi1UMdPVVVXw9DKT1MbSOjk2PpZGWpqxhlp/k/TMNP8DwA)

Slightly more interesting but longer; relies on the same logic as above to generate the size of the top of each tower.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T8NPs7g0V6M0LyezuETDN7FAozi1UMdPVVXX0ErXT9vQyk8nx9bPylBTM85I83@ahpnmfwA "R – Try It Online") for the second one.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
Rr_"N%RƊF²S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z@oKF7JTzXoWJfboU3B////NwMA)

```
R              Range [1..n]
 r             Range each to n: [[1..n], [2..n], …, [n]]
    N%RƊ       [(-n)%1, …, (-n)%n]
  _"           Vectorize subtract
        F²S    Flatten, square, sum
```

Comment: Perhaps unsurprisingly, this is not as short as my "surprisingly terse Jelly solution", however, it's certainly a nice answer.

Comment: @JonathanAllan maybe you can at least give a hint? :)

Comment: Hint added to the question - I know that you know what I've said in it, but it might help as an anchor of sorts.

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>47</s> 38 bytes

Prompts for N

```
+/∊((((n=0)×i)+n←i|N)+¯1+⌽⍳¨i←⍳N←⎕)*¨2
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv7b@o44uDSDIszXQPDw9U1M7DyiZWeOnqX1ovaH2o569j3o3H1qRCRQEMvxAVN9UTa1DK4z@A/Vz/U/jMuRK4zICYmMgNgFiUyA2NDDgAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L(%ā.sR+˜nO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fR0P1SKNecZD26Tl5/v//mwEA) or [verify the first 25 test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9k6upnr6TwqG2SgpK9n8t/Hw3VI416xUHap@fk@f/X@Q8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
    #  e.g. input=6
L   # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
    #  STACK: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
(   # Negate each value
    #  STACK: [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6]
%   # Modulo the implicit input by these values
    #  STACK: [0,0,0,-2,-4,0]
ā   # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
    #  STACK: [0,0,0,-2,-4,0],
    #         [1,2,3,4,5,6]
.s  # Get its suffixes
    #  STACK: [0,-4,-2,0,0,0],
    #         [[6],[5,6],[4,5,6],[3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
R   # Reverse the list of suffixes
    #  STACK: [0,-4,-2,0,0,0],
    #         [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6],[5,6],[6]]
+   # Add the values in the two lists at the same positions together
    #  STACK: [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2],[6]]
˜   # Flatten to a single list
    #  STACK: [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,1,2,6]
n   # Square each integer
    #  STACK: [1,4,9,16,25,36,4,9,16,25,36,9,16,25,36,4,9,16,1,4,36]
O   # Sum them together
    #  STACK: 337
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: I have 9 in the legacy version which could probably be golfed (My 05AB1E never was great :p) or might be possible in less using the current version. It uses a trick I feel is not all that likely to be found though ...let's see!

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
N=>eval('for(k=n=0;n++<N;)for(c=e=N%n||n;c<=e+N-n;)k+=c*c++')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctNDoIwEEDhq8zG0NrBgP@mjEfoBYyLprZGqVMDyIq7V9i@fO9tR9u77vUdSk4PnwNlQ1c/2iiKkDrRElOlWanGaLkER57MiqeJtWvIK1Oylq0it3ZKFTLPBoRL3A/Avw@kALcaYYuwQ9gjHBCOCCeEM8IFoa7uEhadot/E9BRBzJeUOv8B)

-2 by Polichinelle.

Iteratively calculates sum, which is shorter than direct calculation.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. I'm testing out a possible new solution that forgoes that stuff entirely, but if that doesn't work out, I'll apply your suggestion.

Comment: -2 bytes: `for(c=e=N%n||n;c<=e+N-n;k+=c*c++);k` -> `for(c=e=N%n||n;c<=e+N-n;)k+=c*c++`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 37 bytes

```
N->sum(n=1,N,sum(i=n,N,(i-(-N)%n)^2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxCoAwDEDRqwRBSKCB1r09Qo4guLRkMJaq569x@bzh92Motz4r5Clc7vdEyylI@KXZXKiMLLQa7RvRrNdA8QVSjAH6UHtQYAEunopC/nw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 71 bytes

```c
s;h;n;x;f(N){for(s=n=0;N/++n;)for(h=-~N-n,x=N%n?:n;h--;++x)s+=x*x;n=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVTBbtswDL33K4QABZLaQSVSEqV53g7DrvmBtYfCdZpgm1vEAWasyD592aOStmuCyDL5SD0@UumWD113PI7NphmaqVnPV4vn9eNuPrZDa5vVdVUNzUINm3b5Z7Uc6qldXQ6fPwzNZrlsqmpajFU7XU3N0I7N4bgd9ubn3XaYL8zzhcFHDf301Hf7/v7brWnNs6tNrg2l2iRbG@d9bZilNj4EeEhtFABy2WOlkLB6isB7nwEWGxVoPbI4hGsAU9a3bC1cBIA@Uii5gQGEJQrrIayQkDlafTiKyMiUEJ4iBbw56xx5feboRZPHpDGOE0e1i5XCPPmgbAkHJD3POxeAJwlBqyOhFJGWKQrpMyZWvHc@ZtKafCKllDNF1BicFZuUVCyMI@MLu56u@kjgoP4UxTJ4piDsVYkYk9J3luQkn2PrhHSTRU4lBHBXDKPwpEWAYirSBUGhWp5Ai1Jnijaq3GRB2JcNaRHYgGgi7Yr3wRGV9ninbNAgZEJmyiDiFJyTJQoqAHaqLOhmeLUZLrND7ZzIZwV7NC36og4l4Vw65bN22icfnTYe1aMx2ja2KTptY8whqAYhkdhcRIOcyidyDlaHIkI3p/0Rh7wWh4okFhVKIBySQ0qXKWhd0Dbn8xwqa2w8ZWFbxkIkFxEtjgpKHx3DyJRhgOjecxFdYnSsXpAVOY0OvNaq7mwJjS@7LJl1YBzmiDlobHA6e/7QlLvTPQ7j3nSbu90V1r773u9OV2h2M32lmyl/wS/MavP/O8/O0bi0Zq7Xbzvc9xPCbHPefjTj9nf/uJ6/XMzF9dlw9WppTFUV9KIkO13mlwu9R7ZTqsq45p1rhGs93y/eW3tYX/8FSuTtG@BpB8h6Pru8N8tPBuvleDOgqn1txvq18L5tx9tz2sPF4fi3W/@4exiPy1//AA)

Inputs an integer \$N>0\$.
Returns the number of blocks needed to make a truncated square pyramid garden of size \$N\$.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

```javascript
f=(N,n=N)=>n&&f(N,n-1)+(g=k=>n++<=N&&k*k+g(k+1))(N%n||n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBDoIwEEX3nmIW2Mw4YmAt4xF6BhqkjZZMCRg3wNlrXf33Xv7bfd06LK/5U2t6jjl7QXtVsSQPNcb/pW6JMUgshbkTa0y8RA4YuSVCe9Z9V8o@Lagg0N5BoSvbNIWY6QQwJF3TNN6mFLB3WG16ULlWm0elo6f8Aw)

---

## Faster, 66 bytes

A longer version that works in \$O(N)\$:

```javascript
f=(N,n=N,k=N%n||n)=>n&&f(N,n-1)-(g=x=>x*(x+++x)*x/6)(k-1)+g(k+N-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBDoIwEEX3nqILJDMMVdiw0eEIPQMNUqKQqQFjmgBnr3X1X977L/u1a7883x8t/jHE6BhMKWzKic1Z9l2QW8lz97e6Rg0jB25DAYGIAhbh2iBMqdAIExktGJ1fQBSr@qZE3dNWVSIiPCnVe1n9PFxmP0JnIdvkwHTNNgeCR4fxBw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ịṡ¥Ɱ¹²FS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//4buL4bmhwqXisa7CucKyRlP/w4cpWf//MTAw)

Uses the very clever tip supplied, but I'm not sure this quite inspires the description "surprisingly terse" yet... that `¹` just smells wrong!

More equivalent 8-byters:

- `ṡR⁸ịⱮ²FS`
- `ịⱮṡR$²FS`
- `` ịⱮṡⱮ`²FS ``
- `RɓịⱮṡ²FS`

```
   Ɱ¹       For each n in [1 .. N],
 ṡ          get a list of all substrings of [1 .. N] of length n,
ị ¥         and take the one at modular 1-index N.
     ²      Square each,
      F     flatten,
       S    and sum.
```

Comment: Getting there, your sense of smell seems good too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
ＮθＩΣＥθΣＸ⁺⊕…ιθ﹪θ±⊕ι²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcs7DsIwEEXRnlW4nJFMQ0GTkipFIousYHBGwZI/sWPD8gdMx6tucZ59UrGJvMgY91bnFh5cIONwMsXFCjc6KiwtwEQ7ZK16mvT@GuPbAWO0hQPHyivcKW4MTquMqNWU1uZTv8y8UeU/6hC7ueBvg8hVzi//AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Inspired by @KevinCruijssen's and @ovs's answers. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                  Input `N` as a number
     θ              Input `N`
    Ｅ               Map over implicit range
          …         Range from
           ι        Current value
            θ       To input `N`
         ⊕          Vectorised Increment
        ⁺           Vectorised Plus
              θ     Input `N`
             ﹪      Modulo
                 ι  Current value
                ⊕   Incremented
               ±    Negated
       Ｘ          ² Vectorised Squared
      Σ             Take the sum
   Σ                Take the sum
  Ｉ                 Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>54</s> 46 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..n).sum{|x|(x..n).sum{|y|(n%-x+y)**2}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNQTy9PU6@4NLe6pqJGowLBq6zRyFPVrdCu1NTSMqqtrf1foABSbGigqZebWKChlqb5HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 27 bytes

```
roJngsaj.%jiS~]q?+Z]FLqS[ms
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9WZmhgUP2/KN8rL704MUtPNSszuC620F47KtbNpzA4Orf4f627/38A)

Port of [Kevin Cruijssen's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243170/91386) answer

```
ro    # Range [1..N]
J     # Dup
ng    # Negate
sa    # Non-destructive length
j.%   # Modulo (implicit zip)
j     # Reorder stack
iS    # Generate tails
~]    # Drop final
q?+Z] # Zip and sum
FL    # Flatten
qS[   # Square
ms    # Map sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

Much of this post is in spoiler blocks, just in case anyone wants to try to find it for themselves since I mentioned it in the question.

> ```
> ịⱮẆ²S
> ```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4buL4rGu4bqGwrJT/8OH4oKs//8xMDA)**

#### How?

> Unrelated String got to the method [in their answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243269/53748), just not to the golfed code!
>
> ```
> ịⱮẆ²S - Link: integer, N
>   Ẇ   - all sublists of [1..N]
>           e.g. N=6 -> [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]
>                       ,[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]
>                       ,[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]
>                       ,[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]
>                       ,[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6]
>                       ,[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>                       ]
>           i.e. for size in [1..N]:
>                  for start in [1..N+1-len]
>                    [start..start+size]
>  Ɱ    - for each sublist:
> ị     -   N index into sublist
>           - indexing in Jelly is 1-indexed and modular so...
>           e.g 6 ị [3,4,5,6] -> 4
>           i.e N ị [start..start+size]
>               -> (N mod size)+start-1 if (N mod size) != 0 else start+size
>         e.g. 6 ịⱮ (6Ẇ) ->  [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,1,2,6]
>               ...if these were grouped in lengths of [N..1] they
>                  are our tower level side lengths:
>                    [[1,2,3,4,5,6]  (height 6: [top..bottom])
>                    ,[2,3,4,5,6]    (height 5: [top..bottom])
>                    ,[3,4,5,6]      (height 4: [top..bottom])
>                    ,[2,3,4]        (height 3: [top..bottom])
>                    ,[1,2]          (height 2: [top..bottom])
>                    ,[6]            (height 1: [top..bottom])
>                    ]
>    ²  - square (vectorises)
>     S - sum
> ```

Comment: ...wow. I'm actually in awe. I thought that builtin might be involved somehow, but never thought about the structure of its output like that!